# How to prevent controls from capturing KeyDown events while a modal form is open?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, keydown

I have a form with CancelButton and AcceptButton (named btnCancel and btnOK). And I have some ComboBoxes as input fields.

ComboBoxes prevent my AcceptButton and CancelButton to receive Escape and Enter keys, so I added this code to KeyDown event for all fields:

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
{
    ComboBox field = (ComboBox)sender;
    if ((field.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.Simple) || (!field.DroppedDown))
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        btnCancel.PerformClick();
    }
}
else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
{
    ComboBox field = (ComboBox)sender;
    if ((field.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.Simple) || (!field.DroppedDown))
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        btnOK.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

This is the code in Clicked event of OK button:

```
if (!changesAreSaved)
{
    SaveChangesToNode();
}

List<int> invalidIndices = ValidateAndRefineNodes(true);

if (invalidIndices.Count == 0)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, "Enter correct values for all fields before you press OK.", "Cannot Save Information",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Everything is OK but when a ComboBox has Focus and I press Enter key on my keyboard, btnOK_Clicked calls Fields_KeyDown again **only** when it shows its MessageBox (on else part of if). Exactly right after MessageBox.Show(...) is being called, KeyDown event is being called for second time without any reason.

This is Call Stack for first call:

[image: This is Call Stack for first call]

And this is for second:

[image: This is Call Stack for second call]

Second call should not occur at all. In second Call Stack, first btnOK_Click (third line) again calls Fields_KeyDown (second line) **from MessageBox.Show(...)**. How is this possible? I'm confused...

Call Stack for second call with External Code visible:

[image: Call Stack with External Code visible]

Comment: Can you provide a short but *complete* example of this? Just a single button, as simple as you can make it.

Comment: Did you remember to set `e.Handled` to true?  If you don't do that, then windows may try to find some other window to handle the event, so it may try delivering it to the form, which may in turn deliver it to the buttons.  Or something like that, anyway.  It is worth trying it.

Comment: Jon, this form edits some information. When OK button is clicked, if all of information are valid and correct, form returns edited information and closes, otherwise it shows the message and doesn't close. I receive two messages one after one instead of only one message.

Comment: Mike, this article: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) says setting SuppressKeyPress to true, also sets Handled to true. Yes, I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Are you closing the message box by *clicking* the button, or pressing a key (space/enter/etc)?

Comment: Rob, sorry, I forgot to say. Clicking button doesn't make any problem. Hitting Enter key is the issue.

Comment: Mike, Nope! Problem persists. e.Handled is always false, even if I set it manually.

Comment: @maxeemo Your issue is then that the fields still have focus while the message box is open, it's not to do with an event being dispatched twice. I haven't worked with desktop apps for a while, so I can't help you unfortunately, but I'd recommend making a new question, as most of this question does not apply. The new question is simply: How to prevent controls from capturing keydown events while a modal form is open. I will flag this question as 'a problem that can no longer be reproduced', as the question is now very misleading for future readers and masks the real cause.

Comment: @maxeemo Why are you hooking KeyDown at all? IMO ComboBoxes **do not** prevent Accept/Cancel buttons when not DroppedDown. Except for Simple style, is that the case?

Comment: Can you give us the code inside FocusOnFirstField(bool)`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes it seems he is using ComboBox in simple mode. `field.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.Simple`

Comment: @Alireza, it does nothing to what happens. I comment it out, but problem is persisting.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've noticed that code, but not sure if it's the "real case" or "just in case" :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev, Yes. My ComboBoxes switch between all three dropdown styles at run-time.

Comment: @maxeemo I think it's better to separate **Why** from **How to solve the problem** questions.

Comment: @maxeemo Can you give us also the stack trace for the external code here?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. I have combined the two questions, since you received helpful answers on both of them. In the future, instead of posting the question again, use the [edit] link under the question to improve your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot correctly process Escape and Enter key in KeyDown event because they are handled during the keyboard preprocessing phase - [Control.IsInputKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Control.ProcessDialogKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey(v=vs.110).aspx).  Normally controls do that for you, but looks like there is a bug in `ComboBox` implementation when `DropDownStyle` is `Simple`.

To get the desired behavior, create and use your own `ComboBox` subclass like this

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.Simple)
        {
            switch (keyData & (Keys.KeyCode | Keys.Alt))
            {
                case Keys.Return:
                case Keys.Escape:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

P.S. And of course don't forget to remove your KeyDown event handlers.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, **it worked**. And so yes, it is a bug! I noticed that when a ComboBox has Simple style, its DroppedDown property is always true, and that's the problem with ComboBox. As it says in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.IsInputKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true), IsInputKey's return value depends on DroppedDown property, and with Enter or Escape, it will be always true for simple ComboBoxes. _But_... I think main question still remains...

Answer (score 1):

While I have no idea about the main reason behind this behavior.

But in this situation obviously `KeyDown` event triggers 2 times. (Set a breakpoint and you will see.)

Since you need to handle it in code, You can try this to neglect one of <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys:

```
bool handled = true;
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        /*Prevent handling the Enter key twice*/
        handled = !handled;
        if(handled)
            return;

        //Rest of logic
        //OkButton.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Reza, I'm sure that some tricky patch like this will fix the issue, but I'm looking for a reasonable way to overcome this. Although this seems to be a bug and needs patch! Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @maxeemo You are welcome :) at the moment I have no Idea about the reason, and I shared this solution only trying to help you, Hope you find it helpful :)